# A GUI that runs on a remote computer, not the server?

Tags: command-line, server, ssh, gui, remote

In the past I have used Webmin to manage my linux servers. These days I primarily work off the command-line.

I'm aware that one can install a GUI on linux servers, but this makes things much heavier and opens up potential security holes.

What I'm wondering is if there is a tool that essentially runs over SSH and behind-the-scenes utilizes CLI tools.

Comment: You can always view any gui app remotely with X forwarding. You will need some pieces of xwindows but not run a manager.  I don't know of a gui "one-stop-shop" like webmin that is a linux gui however.

Comment: **Excellent question.** I have been working on the design for one, and its 'required' functionality, for some time. *Do you have any specific requirements?*

Comment: @david6 will you be making this into an open source project? commercial software? I'd suggest the best way to think about requirements is to look at an app like Webmin. It allows one to perform all sorts of common maintenance functions...

Comment: Here's a thought: how about a compromise ~  a light GUI such as blackbox or 9wm plus ssh with X forwarding ? GUI don't have to start on the server itself ,but once you ssh there , you have an option for startx

Answer (score 1):

"behind-the-scenes uses CLI tools" is not a valid concept. Just adding a layer of interpretation between the user and the system calls adds no security.

Any X Windows program respects its `$DISPLAY` environment variable. You can set up a tunnel for the X protocol FROM the X client on the server TO the X  server on your remote management system  (`man ssh`), and tell the  X  server on your remote management system to accept remote connections. `man xhost`